# vlc wont play multiple instances

Tags: nvidia, vlc, multiple-instances

I read these instructions:

https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/

and my settings are already that which are recommended. But when I go to open multiple windows, in vlc, one closes, and something else opens.

I think multiple windows used to be default but whatever. I have Ubuntu Mate 15.10, and a Nvidea GeForce GTX 460 so I know graphic processing ability isn't an issue.

[image: vlc setup]

Unless I'm being stupid, I don't see what the problem is. How can I have multiple VLC instances open concurrently?

Comment: Did you try unchecking "Use only one instance when started from file manager"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact as edwinksl has pointed out you appear to have left one of the vital settings *checked*:

```
Use only one instance when started from file manager
```

instead of having it *unchecked*. Works nicely with this setting *unchecked* when I tested on my own system:

[image]

A little difficult to listen to both at once mind you :)

**Note:** There are some limitations on this technique which I suspect you have bumped up against:

1. You can only have a single window open if you open files directly with 'File -> Open' from *within a single running vlc*.
2. However you can use 'File -> Open' from *multiple separate open vlc instances* and thereby play multiple files.
3. You can have many vlc windows playing individual media files as in my screenshot, when you use: 'right click + Open in vlc'. You can do this multiple times and this is my own preferred technique from within a file manager.

Hopefully [this is clear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ9f2rnjB84)?

**References:**

- [How to play multiple instances of VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/)

Comment: I was launching vlc from vlc, which is evidently also the "file-manager".