# Can't play multiple videos in VLC, ubuntu-gnome

Tags: gnome, video, vlc

I'm using ubuntu-gnome 17.04

I know how to make VLC play multiple videos simultaneously by unchecking the 'Allow only one instance' option. It works fine in Windows and normal Ubuntu but there seem to be some problem with ubuntu-gnome, I also unchecked 'Use only one instance when started from file manager' but it still doesn't work. Anyone knows how to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/799485/vlc-wont-play-multiple-instances

Comment: @Redbob The OP states in the question that using the solution in the linked question "still doesn't work".